# Why does my button dosen't submit the form using ajax and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to understand why my form isn't submitting, but I don't know why.
I've tried to console.log the values of the array values and it works perfectly.

When I click on the submit button of the form it simply show the alert "ok" and reload the page, but doesn't submit the form...

```
<form method="POST">
    <?php 
    while($service = $req->fetch()){ ?>

            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="checkbox" class="getValue" value="<?= $service['price']; ?>">

              <label><?= $service['service']; ?></label>
              <strong><?= $service['price']; ?>€</strong>
            </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // annul action par défaut du button

    var values = [];

    $('.getValue').each(function(){

        if($(this).is(":checked")){ 
            values.push($(this).val()); 
        }
    });

    values = values.toString();

    // PROBLEME HERE:
    $.ajax({
        url:"addServicesRequest.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{values:values},
        success:function(data){
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: FYI: `e.preventDefault();` is useless since a button with `type=button` doesn't have any native behavior that would need to be prevented. But have you opened your developer's console and looked at the Console tab for errors and the Network tab to see if the request is even being made?

Comment: i've deleted it thanks

@ScottMarcus the form still dosen't submit :(

here's the network tab : https://ibb.co/GFyy3ck

Comment: Try removing the e.preventDefault? And maybe set the button type as submit

Comment: @Chris it's done, but still does not work

Comment: @Chris No. If you set the button type to `submit`, then you need `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: So, if you click on that item in the Network tab, you'll be able to investigate the Request as well as the Response. Then you can verify that you are getting back what you think you are. According to your picture, you are getting a 200 status, which means that the request worked.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks
I'm going to inspect that
thanks a lot for your time

Comment: And when you say, it doesn't submit the form, how do you know that? What does the `addServicesRequest.php` page do with the data?

Comment: this is what's in the addServicesRequest.php : https://codeshare.io/UbKVU and here is a screen of my database : https://ibb.co/ZHdS57T

Comment: Are you sure `values` should be converted to a string before they get posted to your form processor? I would add some sort of simple log to the form processor page to verify that it's getting hit.

Comment: I tried to echo the value of $_POST['values'] (console.log and alert), but doesn't show anithing and I removed the toString conversion

Comment: I've got it working ! the error was that I put <button type="button></button> instead of <button></button> Thanks for your help, it appreciated it a lot

Answer (score -2):

I've got it working ! the error was that I put  instead of  and I removed the e.preventDefault();